# How to lower Flash video resources usage for Chrome minimized?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, cpu-load

I noticed that minimized or not makes no difference for CPU usage when playing Flash video in Chrome. How to fix that (seems obviously not right)?

What makes it annoying is that I have video decoding done by software.

Answer (score 1):

Changing active tab to empty while playing Flash video in another tab lowers resources usage.

Same is done by reducing video quality.